# Не получается сделать обратную совместимость с API 23 и ниже

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Создал "Signed APK" в Android Studio и попытался его установить на другие устройства. На устройствах ниже API 23 не устанавливается. Стал проверять в эмуляторе Genymotion. Порылся в логах устройства, и нашел как я думаю, причину ошибки:

```
07-13 16:46:36.646 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2414): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12525000 but found 11509470
07-13 16:46:36.646 E/Finsky  ( 2414): [135] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.ca.b(53): GMSCore is missing, disabled or the version installed is older than the one required by this client
07-13 16:46:36.650 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2414): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12525000 but found 11509470
07-13 16:46:36.650 E/Finsky  ( 2414): [135] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.ca.b(53): GMSCore is missing, disabled or the version installed is older than the one required by this client
```

Как исправить приложение, что бы оно устанавливалось хотя бы на API 21 (Android 5.0) и выше? Если причина не в GMSCore, то в чем?

P.s. Логи устройства, и файлы проекта(манифест, и build.gradle) можно найти тут: https://github.com/Nulllix/debug

Comment: Хм... если просто перекинуть apk в эмулятор, то он автоматический установиться, а если в папке, то не устанавливается.

Comment: https://youtu.be/sl9szM3bgCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете версию play service sdk 15, а на устройстве стоит старая (необновленная) версия. Play service на устройстве обновляются сразу как зайдете по какимто google id. Чтобы дать пользователю подсказку вам надо делать:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

> Another approach is to use the isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() method.
>   You get a reference to the singleton object that provides this method
>   using GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(). You might call this method
>   in the onResume() method of the main activity. If the result code is
>   SUCCESS, then the Google Play services APK is up-to-date and you can
>   continue to make a connection. If, however, the result code is
>   SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, or SERVICE_DISABLED,
>   then the user needs to install an update.

Comment: Возможно мне так же помогло то что, при создании "Signed APK" я отметил две галочки, а не одну. https://ibb.co/i2TV9J . В любом случае, на эмуляторе все устанавливается, когда проверю на реальном устройстве, сообщу) Спасибо)